# Kusto Group By Query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have some log data structured like:

```
{
    timestamp: mm/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss
    customDimensions : {
      location: "locationA",
      subLocation: "subLocationB",
      dataName: "dataNameB",
      data: "value"
    } 
}
```

I need to return the latest record for each "dataName" by location/subLocation.

e.g.

```
locationA sublocationB dataName value
locationA sublocationC dataName value
locationA sublocationB dataname2 value
```

Basically perform a "group by" on fields: location,sublocation, and dataName where max(timestamp)

How can I achieve this with Kusto as there is no group by support and the summarize function seems to require an aggregate function?

Answer (score 2):

You could try extending the dynamic properties into calculated columns, then summarizing using `arg_max()` to get the latest (according to `timestamp`) by `location`, `subLocation`  and `dataName`.

For example:

```
datatable(d:dynamic)[
    dynamic({
    "timestamp": "2020-05-12 20:32:08",
    "customDimensions" : {
      "location": "locationA",
      "subLocation": "subLocationB",
      "dataName": "dataNameB",
      "data": "value"
        } 
    }), dynamic({
    "timestamp": "2020-05-12 20:35:08",
    "customDimensions" : {
      "location": "locationA",
      "subLocation": "subLocationB",
      "dataName": "dataNameB",
      "data": "value"
        } 
    }), dynamic({
    "timestamp": "2020-05-12 20:25:08",
    "customDimensions" : {
      "location": "locationB",
      "subLocation": "subLocationB",
      "dataName": "dataNameC",
      "data": "value"
        } 
    })
]
| project timestamp = todatetime(d.timestamp),
          location = tostring(d.customDimensions.location),
          subLocation = tostring(d.customDimensions.subLocation),
          dataName = tostring(d.customDimensions.dataName), data = tostring(d.customDimensions.data)
| summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by location, subLocation, dataName
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is:

```
<name of the table>
| summarize arg_max(customDimensions.dataName) by location, subLocation
```

you are supposed to have extracted a column that contains the "customDimensions" data and that is dynamic.

P.S. Since the column is dynamic, before you can run **arg_max()** you must cast the reference data type for that field.